# API Rest to remove records from a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

I know it can be done with AMPscript or SSJS, but I need to do with a REST API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use REST for deleting records in data extension, as only SOAP supports delete. You can follow the example provided in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/deleting_a_row_from_a_data_extension_via_the_web_service_api.htm), utilising following SOAP payload:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Delete</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d5c8c2ee-384e-4492-af18-b01e0d438b62</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-c10e3bda-13ef-4868-bacd-6e760cd45cf2-1">
            <o:Username>USERNAME</o:Username>
            <o:Password>PASSWORD</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <DeleteRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options></Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>FIRST SEND</CustomerKey>
            <Keys>
               <Key>
                  <Name>EMAIL</Name>
                  <Value>test@example.com</Value>
               </Key>
            </Keys>
         </Objects>
      </DeleteRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: extension data records could be updated with a Rest API call ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @JeferssonGomez: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateDataExtensionIDAsync.htm